# Replace every odd occurrence of space with “_”

Tags: regex, replace, vbscript

I have the following string where I should replace every odd occurrence of space with `_`.

String:

```
901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Local_Relay 907 46 
908 51705 909 306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr
```

Expected String:

```
901_R 902_M 903_Picture_message 904_NA 905_F 906_Local_Relay 907_46 
908_51705 909_306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr
```

I tried taking the space count and also using regular expression occurrence but was not able to hit the mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop and keep a count of spaces found but only act on odd numbers:

```
Dim thing: thing = "901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Local_Relay 907 46 908 51705 909 306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr"
Dim i, counter

For i = 1 To Len(thing)
    If Mid(thing, i, 1) = " " Then
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter Mod 2 Then thing = Left(thing, i - 1) & "_" & Mid(thing, i + 1)
    End If
Next

msgbox thing
```

Comment: Simple, easy to understand and easy to maintain.

Comment: [`Mod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/basszbdt(v=vs.84).aspx) has to be one of my favourite operators.

Comment: This method is fine for small amount of data but expect it to slow down significantly on larger datasets to the point it won't run.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to split the string at spaces, append underscores to odd and spaces to even elements (except for the last one), then glue them back together:

```
s = "901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Loc..."

a = Split(s, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(a)-1 Step 2
  a(i) = a(i) & "_"
Next
For i = 1 To UBound(a)-1 Step 2
  a(i) = a(i) & " "
Next

WScript.Echo Join(a, "")
```

If you want to avoid looping twice you can do it in one go like this:

```
s = "901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Loc..."

c = CreateObject("ScriptingDictionary")
c.Add 0, "_"
c.Add 1, " "

a = Split(s, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(a)-1
  a(i) = a(i) & c(i Mod 2)
Next

WScript.Echo Join(a, "")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)

**Update:** Have improved the pattern matching so only white-space characters are detected, so if the data contained `902    R` it would still return `902_R`.

```vb
Dim data: data = "901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Local_Relay 907 46 908 51705 909 306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr"
'Include value of first capture group (\b\d{3})
'and append _ to it, this will make up the replacement value.
Dim value: value = "$1_"
Dim result
Dim rx: Set rx = new RegExp

With rx
  .Global = True
  .IgnoreCase = True
  'Expression checks for word boundary followed by 3 digit value
  'followed by any number whitespace characters.
  .Pattern = "(\b\d{3})\s+"
  result = .Replace(data, value)
End With
Set rx = Nothing

WScript.Echo "--------- Test ----------"
WScript.Echo data
WScript.Echo result
WScript.Echo
```

Output:

```
--------- Test ----------
901 R 902 M 903 Picture_message 904 NA 905 F 906 Local_Relay 907 46 908 51705 909 306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr
901_R 902_M 903_Picture_message 904_NA 905_F 906_Local_Relay 907_46 908_51705 909_306910001112/TYPE=PLMN@mms.cosmote.gr
```

> <sub>**Disclaimer:** I actually missed the "odd" requirement in the question title, this example just uses pattern matching to find occurrences of the repeated pattern in the sample data `<3 digit number><space>` and `Replace()` it with the expected one `<3 digit number><underscore>`.</sub>

---

#### Performance Considerations

On a side note decided to test the performance against the classic `For` loop approach to show why I switched to using Regular Expressions for this type of the scenario, using [@alex-k's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623103/692942) built a timing script that would also allow me to duplicate the source data multiple times to create a larger dataset.

Duplicating the source 100 times

```
RegEx Method
String Length: 11999
Start: 55250.37109375
Stop: 55250.40234375
Diff: 0.03125

For loop - Mod Method
String Length: 11999
Start: 55250.40234375
Stop: 55250.4375
Diff: 0.03515625
```

A small increase at 1000 times

```
RegEx Method
String Length: 119999
Start: 55348.5859375
Stop: 55348.9375
Diff: 0.3515625

For loop - Mod Method
String Length: 119999
Start: 55348.9375
Stop: 55350.04296875
Diff: 1.10546875
```

But look what happens if we up that to 5000 times

```
RegEx Method
String Length: 599999
Start: 55545.69140625
Stop: 55547.4296875
Diff: 1.73828125

For loop - Mod Method
String Length: 599999
Start: 55547.4296875
Stop: 55584.15234375
Diff: 36.72265625
```

The effect on the `For` loop method is exponential to the point that when I get to 10000 times the RegEx method runs then fails to return in a timely manner when attempting to run the `For` loop method.