# How to remove unknown number of newline using regex

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have text like this.

```
(57) some text
some other text
unknown nubmer of such lines
(12) some text
```

I want to reduce it to

```
(57) some text some other text unknown nubmer of such lines
(12) some text
```

Means space separation instead of newline.

Is it possible using regex find and replace or I need to write a script?

I am able to find using:`\(\d{1,2}\)([\w\W]*?)\(\d{1,2}\)`

It turned out that My data is inconsistent and start and end needs to be defined.

https://regex101.com/r/gB7wR2/2

Comment: Example of how to use `RegExp` `Replace()` method - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36624396/692942 This question has been answered lots of times by various ones.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Let me look into it and see if this is duplicate.

Comment: I'm not saying that example is a duplicate just that the question has been asked multiple times before just look at all the results for [`[vbscript] [regex] is:question replace`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvbscript%5D+%5Bregex%5D+is%3Aquestion+replace) in [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to need a regex-based replacement. Use

```
[\r\n]+(?!\(\d+\))
```

and replace with a space. This expression will match all linebreaks that are not followed with `(`+digit(s)+`)`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI3rN2/1)

```
Dim regEx As Object
Dim result As String
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With regEx
    .pattern = "[\r\n]+(?!\(\d+\))"
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
End With
s = "(57) some text" & vbCrLf & "some other text" & vbCrLf & "unknown nubmer of such lines" & vbCrLf & "(12) some text" & vbCrLf & "(54) sometext" & vbCrLf & "some Text" & vbCrLf & "unknown nubmer of such lines" & vbCrLf & "(51) some text" & vbCrLf & "(86) some text" & vbCrLf & "some Text" & vbCrLf & "some other text" & vbCrLf & "(87) some text"
result = regEx.Replace(s, " ")
```

Result:

```
(57) some text some other text unknown nubmer of such lines 
(12) some text 
(54) sometext some Text unknown nubmer of such lines 
(51) some text 
(86) some text some Text some other text 
(87) some text
```

Comment: This is exactly the answer for my question. But it turns out that my problem is worse than I thought. Thanks for suggestion. This will really help.

Comment: Those no need for late binding, `RegExp` is built into VBScript just use `Set regEx = new RegExp`.